# ORA-00907L missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried create a new script table using this code

```
CREATE TABLE orderheader(
Order_id NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_id NOT NULL CHECK(Order_id > 0),
Order_date DATE,
Order_customer VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCE customer(Cust_id),
Order_delivery NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_deli NOT NULL CHECK (Order_delivery > 0),
Order_total NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_to CHECK (Order_total > 0),
Order_vat NUMBER,
Order_payment NUMBER,
Order_completed DATE,
Order_credit CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT or_cre_ck CHECK (Order_credit IN ('Y', 'N')),
Order_takenby NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_tak CHECK(Order_takenby > 0) REFERENCE employee,
CONSTRAINT orhe_id_cus_deli PRIMARY KEY (Order_customer, Order_delivery, Order_id)
)
```

When I tried to execute this code, this error pops out

```
Error computing plan for statement.
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I looked everywhere, and I tried removing constrains one by one. All end in same results until I remove all constraints. There maybe other errors I do not know. This may look simple, because I just got started with this SQL coding. I have employee, and customer created.

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html) should help.

Comment: A note on the data model. I would expect a table called ORDER_HEADER to have a primary key of ORDER_ID. That is, every ORDER_ID is unique. A compound primary key of CUSTOMER_ID/ORDER_NO would be unusual: it might represent a business (candidate) key but leads to complications when it comes to implementation in a multi-user, high volume environment. CUSTOMER_ID/ORDER_NO/DELIVERY_NO just looks wrong. Even if an order can be split across multiple deliveries, surely that should be tracked at the Order Line level?

Answer (score 1):

`REFERENCE` should be `REFERENCES`

```sql
CREATE TABLE orderheader(
Order_id NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_id NOT NULL CHECK(Order_id > 0),
Order_date DATE,
Order_customer VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES customer(Cust_id),
Order_delivery NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_deli NOT NULL CHECK (Order_delivery > 0),
Order_total NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_to CHECK (Order_total > 0),
Order_vat NUMBER,
Order_payment NUMBER,
Order_completed DATE,
Order_credit CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT or_cre_ck CHECK (Order_credit IN ('Y', 'N')),
Order_takenby NUMBER CONSTRAINT or_tak CHECK(Order_takenby > 0) REFERENCES employee,
CONSTRAINT orhe_id_cus_deli PRIMARY KEY (Order_customer, Order_delivery, Order_id)
)
```

However, if you're going to name the constraints then you should probably name them all:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orderheader(
  Order_id        NUMBER
                  CONSTRAINT or_id_nn NOT NULL
                  CONSTRAINT or_id_ck CHECK(Order_id > 0),
  Order_date      DATE,
  Order_customer  VARCHAR2(10)
                  CONSTRAINT or_cust_fk REFERENCES customer(Cust_id),
  Order_delivery  NUMBER
                  CONSTRAINT or_deli_nn NOT NULL
                  CONSTRAINT or_deli_ck CHECK (Order_delivery > 0),
  Order_total     NUMBER
                  CONSTRAINT or_to_ck CHECK (Order_total > 0),
  Order_vat       NUMBER,
  Order_payment   NUMBER,
  Order_completed DATE,
  Order_credit    CHAR(1)
                  CONSTRAINT or_cre_ck CHECK (Order_credit IN ('Y', 'N')),
  Order_takenby   NUMBER
                  CONSTRAINT or_tak_ck CHECK(Order_takenby > 0)
                  CONSTRAINT or_tak_fk REFERENCES employee,
  CONSTRAINT orhe_id_cus_deli PRIMARY KEY (Order_customer, Order_delivery, Order_id)
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=15f4c5544a07b25d38963d2bade81dc6)*

Comment: Yeah, this works. Thanks for your help.